# Constants in Haskell and pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, pattern-synonyms

How is it possible to define a macro constant in Haskell? Especially, I would like the following snippet to run without the second pattern match to be overlapped.

```
someconstant :: Int
someconstant = 3

f :: Int -> IO ()
f someconstant = putStrLn "Arg is 3"
f _            = putStrLn "Arg is not 3"
```

Comment: You should clarify that you are not looking for a guard `f x | x==someconstant = putStrLn "is 3"`, but you really want a pattern. (Right?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define a [pattern synonym](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PatternSynonyms):

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern SomeConstant :: Int
pattern SomeConstant = 3

f :: Int -> IO ()
f SomeConstant = putStrLn "Arg is 3"
f _            = putStrLn "Arg is not 3"
```

But also consider whether it's not better to match on a custom variant type instead of an `Int`.