# Haskell - Using a constant in pattern matching

Tags: haskell, syntax, pattern-matching, pattern-synonyms

Let's say I have the following code (text in `<>` is a shorthand, not actually part of the code):

```
data A = <something>
defaultA :: A
defaultA = <Really complicated expression of type A>
```

Now I want to have a function pattern match on `defaultA`, like this:

```
f defaultA = <case 1>
f _ = <case 2>
```

However, `defaultA` in the first line becomes a new variable, not a condition that means the parameter will equal `defaultA`. The best way I know to achieve something like what I want is:

```
f x | x == defaultA = <case 1>
f _ = <case 2>
```

Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [a question asked only 15 hours earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417305/constants-in-haskell-and-pattern-matching)! Seriously, couldn't you have seen that? — However, your question is formulated rather better than the other one (and Benjamin Hodgson's answer is much better than [mine over there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35417393/745903)), so I [closed the other question instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9277/180171). But, meh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the definiton of `defaultA` consists only of constructor calls, you could use a [pattern synonym](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#pattern-synonyms).

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

data A = A Int

pattern DefaultA = A 3

isDefaultA DefaultA = putStrLn "it was a default"
isDefaultA _ = putStrLn "it was not a default"
```

This isn't a particularly idiomatic deployment of `PatternSynonyms` though. I'd probably stick with Haskell 98, using a very-slightly-more-verbose guard clause with an equality test.

```
data A = A Int deriving Eq

defaultA = A 3

isDefaultA a
    | a == defaultA = putStrLn "it was a default"
    | otherwise = putStrLn "it was not a default"
```

---

Where pattern synonyms *do* come in useful is for wrapping up noisy library constructor calls imposed on you when you're doing datatype-generic programming with a pattern like *free monads* or [*Data Types a la Carte*](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~swier004/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf).

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

-- fixed point of functor
newtype Expr f = In (f (Expr f))

-- functor coproduct
data (f :+: g) a = Inl (f a) | Inr (g a)


-- now plug in custom code
data Add r = Add_ r r
data Val r = Val_ Int
type HuttonsRazor = Expr (Add :+: Val)

pattern Add x y = In (Inl (Add_ x y))
pattern Val x = In (Inr (Val_ x))

eval :: HuttonsRazor -> Int
eval (Add x y) = eval x + eval y
eval (Val x) = x
```

Comment: "If your defaultA consists only of constructor calls" ... even it is some arbitrary expression, if it admits an Eq instance as in the case of the question, you can still write `pattern DefaultA = ((== defaultA) -> True)` using ViewPatterns.

Comment: Yep, good point, though that requires `ViewPatterns` as well as `PatternSynonyms` (and is still not as simple as a guard clause in my opinion).

Comment: I removed the guards in the Haskell 98 version; I am not against verbosity for the sake of clarity but in this case it doesn't serve to clarify anything.

Comment: @Cubic I put them back. The point is not that I'm pulling a `Bool` out of an `A`, the point is that I'm using guards to test whether it's `defaultA`. Perhaps I should change the return type to clarify that

Comment: I don't quite agree with your recommendation of equality guards – equality comparisons should IMO be avoided as much as possible. But, nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ViewPattern](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns#Examples) extension

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
data A = A Int | B Char deriving (Eq, Show)

complexA = A 34
complexB = B 'z'

isComplexA = (complexA ==)
isComplexB = (complexB ==)

complexF (isComplexA -> True) = print "complexA"
complexF (isComplexB -> True) = print "complexB"
complexF _                    = print "too complex"

main = do
    complexF complexA
    complexF complexB
    complexF $ A 55
```

Comment: He can, but if you're just matching against true in the end, you could've just used guards. It seems to me that unless the case the OP is dealing with is more complicated than that just sticking with guards is the better solution.

Comment: @Cubic Well, he want pattern matching (not guards) I think you are right but your comments fit better at the main question. In any case, use `PatternSynonyms` looks a better solution (I think should be the accepted one, adding `ViewPatterns` for not only constructors).